# Is DOM lookup blocking or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, dom, asynchronous, lookup, blocking

I'm curious, when we do in javascript something like:

```
var navigation = document.getElementById('navigation');
```

Is this lookup blocking or asynchronous?

Comment: It's just an immediate function that accesses the DOM data structure. There's nothing to block on.

Comment: Had it been async, it wouldn't be able to return anything.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: What does "synchronous" mean (as an opposite to "asynchronous")? Is it blocking? If so / if not, how is the result obtained? There is the answer..

Comment: dom reads are sync and blocking. dom writes are sometimes either, depending on what else you do.

Answer (score 2):

It's a function with a return value stored in a variable. It simply could not be asynchronous. Besides, the function doesn't create the Element object, it only searches the document and returns its reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful logical test for all such questions:

If you didn't pass a callback to a function or receive a function as the return value from the function, and you expect to do something with the result, then that function must be "blocking" as in not-async because if it was asyncronous then it's not clear where the result should be placed.